# How to find printers on IOS from Brother SDK?

Tags: ios, swift

I find printers from iPad setting print can find my Brother printer.

But when I try the code I get empty device list and I don't know why.

I am not familiar with Swift. I just try the sample code from Official documentation.
https://support.brother.com/g/s/es/htmldoc/mobilesdk/guide/discover-printer.html

Here is my code:

```
func getPrinter() {

    let printerManager = BRPtouchNetworkManager()

     printerManager.setPrinterName("Brother QL-720NW")
     printerManager.startSearch(5)

    printerManager.getPrinterNetInfo()

    print("start")
    let testFind = YourClass()

    print("1")
    testFind.startSearchWiFiPrinter()
    testFind.didFinishSearch(printerManager)
    print("2")
  }

class YourClass: NSObject, BRPtouchNetworkDelegate {
    private var networkManager: BRPtouchNetworkManager?

    func startSearchWiFiPrinter() {
      print("3")
      let manager = BRPtouchNetworkManager()
      manager.delegate = self
      manager.startSearch(5)
      self.networkManager = manager
    }

    // BRPtouchNetworkDelegate
    func didFinishSearch(_ sender: Any!) {
      print("4")
      guard let manager = sender as? BRPtouchNetworkManager else {
        print("5")
        return
      }
      guard let devices = manager.getPrinterNetInfo() else {
        print("6")
        return
      }
      print(devices)
      print("7")
      for deviceInfo in devices {
        print("8")
        if let deviceInfo = deviceInfo as? BRPtouchDeviceInfo {
          print("Model: \(deviceInfo.strModelName), IP Address: \(deviceInfo.strIPAddress)")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I call my function `getPrinter()` and here is my print log:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK documentation gives you an example implementation of two methods:

```
func startSearchWiFiPrinter() {}
```

and

```
func didFinishSearch(_ sender: Any!) {}
```

In the class you want to execute the search you must implement these. You also need to declare the class to attend the protocol `BRPtouchNetworkDelegate`. The last thing is to have a property to be able to hold the Network manager (Which is done in the line: `private var networkManager: BRPtouchNetworkManager?`)

However, you are not supposed to call the "didFinishSearch" method by yourself.  When you call `startSearchWiFiPrinter`, the search begins, and the BRPtouchNetworkManager instance **itself** calls the `didFinishSearch` method. It is capable of doing so because you set the delegate in the line: `manager.delegate = self`.

You should not need 2 classes for this. You should not use 2 instances of BRPtouchNetworkManager either.

Try this. Remember the number you put as an argument to `startSearchWiFiPrinter` means how long in seconds the search will be.

```
class EXAMPLEClass: NSObject, BRPtouchNetworkDelegate {
    private var networkManager: BRPtouchNetworkManager?
    func getPrinter() {
         self.startSearchWiFiPrinter()
    }

    func startSearchWiFiPrinter() {
      let manager = BRPtouchNetworkManager()
      manager.delegate = self
      manager.setPrinterName("Brother QL-720NW")
      manager.startSearch(5)
      self.networkManager = manager
    }

    // BRPtouchNetworkDelegate
    func didFinishSearch(_ sender: Any!) {
      print("4")
      guard let manager = sender as? BRPtouchNetworkManager else {
        print("5")
        return
      }
      guard let devices = manager.getPrinterNetInfo() else {
        print("6")
        return
      }
      print(devices)
      print("7")
      for deviceInfo in devices {
        print("8")
        if let deviceInfo = deviceInfo as? BRPtouchDeviceInfo {
          print("Model: \(deviceInfo.strModelName), IP Address: \(deviceInfo.strIPAddress)")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !  I will try the code later and let you know.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for late, You explain  very clear, I try the code and call the fun `startSearchWiFiPrinter`, but `didFinishSearch` doesn't be triggered.

Comment: harrumph.  Been trying to get this working with Swift 5/Xcode12/iOS 14 and the code crashes.  Hard to know where it crashes, it's somewhere in the library/framework.

Comment: Do this solution listed the printer ?? @RobCohen